# Conditional input step in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

using Jenkins `v2.138.2` and workflow-aggregator `v2.6`, I'm trying to define a conditional `input` step that depends on the value of a job parameter as follows:

```
stage('apply') {

  when { expression { params.apply_plan != 'no' } }

  if (params.apply_plan != 'yes') {
    input {
      message 'Apply this plan?'
    }
  }

  steps {
    withAWS(region: 'us-east-1', role: assume_role) {
      dir(path: tf_dir) {
        sh "make apply"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However this `if { ( ... ) input { ...} }` syntax gives me a run-time error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.InputStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong syntax here. The `input { … }` is only valid as a directive (outside of the `steps` directly below `stage`). What you want to use is the `input` step which is described [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#-input-%20wait%20for%20interactive%20input). Basically you just need to remove the curly braces and put it into a `script` within `steps`:

```
stage("stage") {
    steps {
        script {
            if (params.apply_plan != 'yes') {
                input message: 'Apply this plan?'
            }
        }
        withAWS(region: 'us-east-1', role: assume_role) {
            dir(path: tf_dir) {
                sh "make apply"
            }
         }
     }
 }
```